# How to check is it mock runtime?

Tags: pallet, substrate-node-template, runtime, mock

I have a function

```
//for testing purposes only!
pub fn some_fn(n: T::BlockNumber) {
    SomeStorage::<T>::set(n);
}
```

for testing purposes only!

How to check is it a mock runtime?

something like that

```
let is_mock = frame_system::is_mock_runtime!
```

But frame_system::is_mock_runtime macros does not exist.

Please give me advise how to check is it a mock runtime or not.
Thanks.

Happy New Year!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Were does this function live? Is it inside a pallet?

In any case you can use Rust features to make it available only for testing like this:

```rust
// Std is never enabled in the Runtime.
// This function can only be called from testing but not from the pallet itself:
#[cfg(feature = "std")]
pub fn some_fn(n: T::BlockNumber) {
```

```rust
// Or you can restrict it to testing, which only works from the same crate since the
// 'test' feature does not propagate to dependencies:
#[cfg(test)]
pub fn some_fn(n: T::BlockNumber) {
    SomeStorage::<T>::set(n);
}
```

This is being done in the the Generalized Message Queue pallet to shield its [debug_info()](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/b3d9f3c57e7f799d49442e3456614431f2d0e51a/frame/message-queue/src/lib.rs#L1083) function from accidental production use.